# Correction of two algorithms calculates empty lines

Tags: vba, algorithm, excel

Is it possible to correct the two algorithms? when I do a filtering by criteria, I calculate two columns, "Pareto_Analysis" and "cumulates", my problem is: that the two algorithms don't calculate the data filtered, but calculate all the lines.

Here is an example of filtering on this screen printer

[image]

**Code algorithm for "Pareto_Analysis"**:

```
Sub calculDefect()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet7
With ws
    Const SourceColumn As String = "G"
    Const DestColumn As String = "K"
    Const TotalCell As String = "H4"  'total defect of all defect
    Const StartRow As Integer = 11
    Const EndRow As Integer = 100

    For i = StartRow To EndRow
       ws.Range(DestColumn & i).Formula = "=(" & SourceColumn & i & "/" & TotalCell & ")*100"
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

**Code algorithm for "cumule"**:

```
Sub calculatCumule()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet7
With ws
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("L11") = Range("K11").Value
    Range("L12").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-1]"
    Range("L12").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L12:L" & LastRow & "")
End With

End Sub
```

---

To clarify the question further, here are some more screen dumps:

Here I chose the criteria I wanted:
[image: Here I chose the criteria I wanted]

Displays the data I have chosen:
[image: Displays the data I have chosen]

Calculate the "pareto" column based on the column  "Quantity_prod" and the column"cumule"  based on the column "pareto":
[image: Calculate the "pareto" column based on the column "Quantity_prod" and the column"cumule" based on the column "pareto"]
And if you notice in the last picture the rest of the columns has 0 and 100 that repeats, normally should just calculate the 4 lines.

Comment: `calculatCumule` shouldn't need modifications. The `EndRow` value in `calculDefect` is a constant (100) and should rather be calculated (look at how Lastrow is calculated in calculatCumule)

Comment: In fact `calculatCumule` could be improved, but here it is not what makes the wrong values appears.

Comment: @Houyam I don't see any filter set to your worksheet (in the picture you attached) , what do you mean by that ? Maybe you should describe better in your post which ranges your "algorithms" suppose to be working ?

Comment: @VincentG - I think the OP wants the formula in `calculatCumule` to use the previous **visible** row instead of `R[-1]C`.  And I suspect that they want to change the formula in cell H4 so that `calculDefect` determines the row's "quantity" as a % of the total **visible** quantity.

Comment: @YowE3K i hope not :) I've already written something that answers the post with understanding something a little different. let's see what the PO wants...

Comment: @ShaiRado - I must admit I hadn't thought of the question as just "how do I find the last used row", but I guess it can be interpreted that way if you ignore the comments about "filtering by criteria".  (And the screen dump doesn't show any filtering being applied, so it's a very likely interpretation.)

Comment: @YowE3K just for you I added the code under **Edit 1**, now it's night time here

Comment: @ShaiRado - You did that for me?!?  Just for me??!?  Aww, shucks, I feel so honoured!  :)  :)  :)  (Now I don't know whether I should point out that you could have just used `.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]/SUBTOTAL(9,C[-4])*100"` for K11:Kx, and `.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R11C[-1]:RC[-1])"` for L11:Lx, where x is your `EndRow` / `LastRow`, without any need for determining what is visible from time to time - i.e. it would auto-calculate based on whatever filter criteria were currently applied.)

Comment: Based on your additional images clarifying your question, the first part of Shai's answer (before he tried to make me happy by including code to handle filtered data :D) should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the 2 modified 'Algorithms" code below.

First, you need to run `Sub calculDefect`, and after run `Sub calculatCumule`.

```
Sub calculDefect()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Const SourceColumn As String = "G"
Const DestColumn As String = "K"
Const TotalCell As String = "H4"  'total defect of all defects
Const StartRow As Long = 11
Dim EndRow As Long, i As Long

Set ws = Sheet7
With ws
    EndRow = .Range("G" & StartRow).End(xlDown).Row '<-- get last row with data in Column G

    For i = StartRow To EndRow
       .Range(DestColumn & i).Formula = "=(" & SourceColumn & i & "/" & TotalCell & ")*100"
    Next i
End With

End Sub

'====================================================================

Sub calculatCumule()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set ws = Sheet7
With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row '<-- get last row with data in Column K
    .Range("L11") = .Range("K11").Value
    .Range("L12").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-1]"
    .Range("L12:L" & LastRow).FillDown
End With

End Sub
```

Screen-shot of the results I've got running this code:

[image]

---

**Edit 1**: same 2 "algorithms" that work when you filter the data:

```
Sub calculDefect()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Const SourceColumn As String = "G"
Const DestColumn As String = "K"
Const TotalCell As String = "H4"  'total defect of all defects
Const StartRow As Long = 11
Dim EndRow As Long, i As Long
Dim VisRng  As Range, C As Range

Set ws = Sheet7
With ws
    EndRow = .Range("G" & StartRow).End(xlDown).Row '<-- get last row with data in Column G

    ' set visible range to only filtered cells in Column G
    Set VisRng = .Range(Range(SourceColumn & StartRow), Range(SourceColumn & EndRow)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    .Range(TotalCell).Formula = WorksheetFunction.Sum(VisRng) '<-- re-calculate Total defects according to visible range

    For Each C In VisRng
        .Range(DestColumn & C.Row).Formula = "=(" & SourceColumn & C.Row & "/" & TotalCell & ")*100"
    Next C
End With

End Sub

'=================================================================

Sub calculatCumule()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim VisRng As Range, C As Range
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Set ws = Sheet7
With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row '<-- get last row with data in Column K

    StartRow = 11 '<-- init value
     ' set visible range to only filtered cells in Column G
    Set VisRng = .Range(Range("K" & StartRow), Range("K" & LastRow)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    StartRow = VisRng.Item(1).Row '<-- update first row in visible range

    For Each C In VisRng
        If C.Row = StartRow Then
            .Range("L" & C.Row) = .Range("K" & C.Row).Value
        Else
            .Range("L" & C.Row).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,K" & StartRow & ":K" & C.Row & ")"
        End If
    Next C

End With

End Sub
```

Screen-shot of the results I've got running this code when filtering "Type_defect" to `CPE02`:

[image]